# How to (sort of) add code to fullcalendar's renderEvents handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar, jquery-events

I'm using fullcalendar 1.6.3 along with Drupal 7 (thus the need, for now, to be back on 1.6.3).  I have some code that I'd like to run every time the view of my calendar changes (via ajax requests) -- forward or backward in time, or between month/week/day view.

Based on some tests, I *could* do this by hacking the source for `renderEvents`:

```
function renderEvents(modifiedEventID) { // TODO: remove modifiedEventID hack
    if (elementVisible()) {
        currentView.setEventData(events); // for View.js, TODO: unify with renderEvents
        currentView.renderEvents(events, modifiedEventID); // actually render the DOM elements
        currentView.trigger('eventAfterAllRender');
        // my_code_here();
    }
}
```

but that would of course be Wrong.  Unfortunately, I can't figure out any other way to do it, probably because of some obvious gap in my Javascript knowledge.  I tried setting up an event handler on `eventAfterAllRender`:

```
var eventAfterAllRenderEvent = new Event('eventAfterAllRender');
document.addEventListener('eventAfterAllRender', function (e) {my_code_here() }, false);
document.dispatchEvent(eventAfterAllRenderEvent);
```

but that (for me) only runs on page load, not after the ajax events.

This is probably more of a Javascript question than a fullcalendar question, but is there any advice out there?  I'm really trying to not hack core; thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs1/event_rendering/eventAfterAllRender/) `eventAfterAllRender` is a callback, so you can do this:

```
$('#your-calendar-element').fullCalendar({
    eventAfterAllRender: function (view) {
        // add your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: This is working; thanks very much.  Sadly, I've still got a problem in that the Drupal Views module is responsible for creating the fullcalendar instance.  As a result, when I add this code I get a second calendar on the page, which of course screws everything up.  But that's a different matter, and not your concern (unless you happen to know the answer :)...